# Add launcher of type Location to Unity application launcher

Tags: unity, launcher

I would like to open a specific file directly from the launcher.

I have created a launcher (myFile.desktop) of type Location, which works like a charm when on the Desktop. I moved it to `/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/` so I can find it over the dash. But I cannot stick it to the laucher (which again is no problem, if I change the type to Application, but then of course it doesn't work any more).

Is this even possible?

I created the laucher via `gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new`

And the .desptop file looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Link
URL=smb://myServer/userhomes/myFiles/arbeitszeit/Zeitkontrolle_6.ods
Name=Zeiterfassung
Icon=/home/andsoon/icon.png
```

Comment: Add the content of the .desktop file to your question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you **modify** *myFile.desktop* file like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Zeiterfassung
Icon=/home/andsoon/icon.png
Exec=xdg-open 'smb://myServer/userhomes/myFiles/arbeitszeit/Zeitkontrolle_6.ods'
```